# Definition of partity in quantized Dirac Theory.

Tags: quantum-field-theory, fermions, dirac-equation, second-quantization, parity

I'm studying from the book "An Introduction to Quantum Field Theory" from Michael E. Peskin and Daniel V. Schroeder, and I read the following:

"The operator *P* should reverse momentum of a particle without flipping its spin. Mathematically, this means that *P* should be implement by a unitary operator which, for example, transforms the state $a_{\textbf{p}}^{s} \left|0\right>$ into $a_{\textbf{-p}}^{s} \left|0\right>$. In other words:
$$P a_{\textbf{p}}^{s} P=\eta_{a} a_{\textbf{p}}^{s}$$
$$P b_{\textbf{p}}^{s} P=\eta_{b} b_{\textbf{p}}^{s},$$
where $\eta_{a}$ and $\eta_{b}$ are possible phases. These phases are restricted by the condition that two applications of parity operator should return observables to their original values. Since observables are built from an even number of fermion operators, this requires $\eta_{a}^2,\eta_{b}^2=\pm1$."

First of all, I suppose there would be $a_{\textbf{p}}^{s\dagger} \left|0\right>$ and $a_{\textbf{-p}}^{s\dagger} \left|0\right>$ (creation operators) instead of $a_{\textbf{p}}^{s} \left|0\right>$ and $a_{\textbf{-p}}^{s} \left|0\right>$ (annihilation operators).
Moreover, I were trying to impose the condition (for example) $P^2HP^2=H$, but something wrong:
\begin{eqnarray}
P^2HP^2 &=& P^2\left[\int{\frac{d^3p}{{2\pi}^3} \sum_{s_{}}(E_{\textbf{p}}a_{\textbf{p}}^{s\dagger}a_{\textbf{p}}^{s}-E_{\textbf{p}}b_{\textbf{p}}^{s\dagger}b_{\textbf{p}}^{s})}\right]P^2 \nonumber \\ &=& \int{\frac{d^3p}{{2\pi}^3} \sum_{s_{}}(E_{\textbf{p}}P^2a_{\textbf{p}}^{s\dagger}P^2P^2a_{\textbf{p}}^{s}P^2-E_{\textbf{p}}P^2 b_{\textbf{p}}^{s\dagger}P^2P^2b_{\textbf{p}}^{s}P^2)} \nonumber  \\  &=& \int{\frac{d^3p}{{2\pi}^3} \sum_{s_{}}(E_{\textbf{p}}(\eta_{a}^{*} \eta_{a})^{2}a_{\textbf{p}}^{s\dagger}a_{\textbf{p}}^{s}-E_{\textbf{p}} (\eta_{b}^{*} \eta_{b})^{2} b_{\textbf{p}}^{s\dagger}b_{\textbf{p}}^{s})} \nonumber \\  &=& \int{\frac{d^3p}{{2\pi}^3} \sum_{s_{}}(E_{\textbf{p}}a_{\textbf{p}}^{s\dagger}a_{\textbf{p}}^{s}-E_{\textbf{p}}b_{\textbf{p}}^{s\dagger}b_{\textbf{p}}^{s})}=H,
\end{eqnarray}
since: \begin{equation} P^2 a_{\textbf{p}}^{s\dagger} P^2=P(P a_{\textbf{p}}^{s\dagger}P)P=P(P a_{\textbf{p}}^{s}P)^{\dagger}P= \eta_{a}^{*}(P a_{\textbf{-p}}^{s}P)^{\dagger}=\eta_{a}^{*}\eta_{a}^{*}a_{\textbf{p}}^{s \dagger}, \end{equation} 
and $\eta_{a}^{*}\eta_{a}=1$. So, it seems that no information about $\eta_{a}$ and $\eta_{b}$ comes from the previous equation. Someone can tell me where I made a mistake?

Comment: I guess you have learned that $\eta$ is a phase from looking at $H$, but why are you looking just at $H$?  There is a constraint for a general observable, which must contain an even number of creation and annihilation operators.  Apply parity twice to an annihilation operator: $P(P a P)P$ must be equal to $\pm a$ which implies $\eta^2 = \pm 1$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, the problem I point out is that the even number in observables means that we have both $a_{\textbf{p}}^{s \dagger}$ and $a_{\textbf{p}}^{s}$. As I show before, it seems that applying a parity transformation to an observable bring to $\eta_{a}^{*} \eta_{a} a_{-\textbf{p}}^{s \dagger}  a_{-\textbf{p}}^{s}=a_{-\textbf{p}}^{s \dagger}  a_{-\textbf{p}}^{s}$, without giving any information on $\eta_{a}$.

Comment: Again, you have learned that $\eta^* \eta = 1$.  You will have to look at other observables to get further constraints.